# How to resolve java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getSentDate()" because "mimeMessage" is null]

Tags: java, spring-boot, email

I am trying to send mails to users when they successfully register their account i.e email verification/confirmation. However, I keep getting the errors above.

This is what the MailCreatorHelper looks like

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MailCreatorHelper {
    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public static String getSiteURL(HttpServletRequest request){
        String siteURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        return siteURL.replace(request.getServletPath(), "");
    }

    private String setVerificationCodeForUser(){
        log.info("Generating authentication code --------------------------------");
        return RandomString.make(35);
    }
    private void setProperties(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.mailgun.org");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator("username", "password");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);


    }

    public MimeMessage createMessage(User user, String siteURL) throws MessagingException {
        setProperties();
        String mailSubject = "Activate your account";
        String sender = "valid@email.com";
        String template = "Dear [[name]],<br>"
                + " Thanks for registering on xxxxxxx"
                + " Kindly click the link below to verify your email and activate your account"
                + " <h4><a href=\"[[URL]]\" target=\"_self\"> Verify email </a></h3>"
                + "Thank you."
                + " xxxx team";

        final Context context = new Context();

        MimeMessage message = this.javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
//        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessage = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessage = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        mimeMessage.setFrom(sender);
        mimeMessage.setSubject(mailSubject);
//        mimeMessage.setReplyTo(sender);
        mimeMessage.setTo(user.getEmail());

//        String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process(template, context);
        template = template.replace("[[name]]", user.getUsername());
        String verifyURL = siteURL + "/user/verify/" + user.getVerificationCode();
        template = template.replace("[[URL]]", verifyURL);
//        mimeMessage.setText(template, true);
        mimeMessage.setText(template);
        log.info(String.valueOf(message));

        return message;

    }

    public MimeMessage createConfirmationEmail(User user, String siteURL) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MessagingException {
        String toAddress = user.getUsername();
        String fromAddress = "valid@email.com";
        String senderName = "Hello, World!";
        String subject = "Welcome to xxxxx";
        String content = "Dear [[name]]," +
                "<br><br>"
                + "Your account have been verified, kindly login to explore<br>"
                + "<h3><a href=\"[[URL]]\" target=\"_self\">Login</a></h3> <br>"
                + "Thank you," +
                "<br><br>"
                + "xxxxx Team";

        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

        helper.setFrom(fromAddress, senderName);
        helper.setTo(toAddress);
        helper.setSubject(subject);

        content = content.replace("[[name]]", user.getUsername());
        String verifyURL = siteURL + "/login" ;

        content = content.replace("[[URL]]", verifyURL);

        helper.setText(content, true);
        return message;

    }

    public MimeMessage createResetPasswordMessage(User user, String siteURL) throws MessagingException {
        setProperties();
        String mailSubject = "Reset your password";
        String sender = "smartsammie@gmail.com";
        String template = "Dear [[name]],<br>"
                + " Kindly click the link below to reset your password"
                + " Ignore this email if you did not make this request"
                + " <h4><a href=\"[[URL]]\" target=\"_self\"> Reset password </a></h3>"
                + "Thank you."
                + " Stay healthy"
                + "xxxxx team";

        final Context context = new Context();

        MimeMessage message = this.javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessage = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        mimeMessage.setFrom(sender);
        mimeMessage.setSubject(mailSubject);
        mimeMessage.setTo(user.getEmail());

//        String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process(template, context);
        template = template.replace("[[name]]", user.getUsername());
        String resetPasswordURL = siteURL + "/user/reset-password/" + user.getVerificationCode();
        template = template.replace("[[URL]]", resetPasswordURL);
//        mimeMessage.setText(template, true);
        mimeMessage.setText(template);
        log.info(String.valueOf(message));

        return message;

    }



    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator
    {
        private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

        public SMTPAuthenticator(String login, String password)
        {
            authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(login, password);
        }

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return authentication;
        }
    }
}
```

What could be wrong? I am not sending any mail in the controller rather I am doing it in the service implementation. I have gone through some couple of threads and nothing seems to work for me

Here is the complete stack trace

```
2021-11-05 18:54:35.547 ERROR 17082 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getSentDate()" because "mimeMessage" is null; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getSentDate()" because "mimeMessage" is null] with root cause

org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getSentDate()" because "mimeMessage" is null
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:491) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at com.etranscript.eTranscriptBackendV2.emailService.services.EmailServiceImpl.sendActivateAccountMessage(EmailServiceImpl.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.etranscript.eTranscriptBackendV2.service.services.ApplicantServiceImpl.register(ApplicantServiceImpl.java:82) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.etranscript.eTranscriptBackendV2.web.api.ApplicantController.registerUser(ApplicantController.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.etranscript.eTranscriptBackendV2.web.api.ApplicantController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$65c3e4b7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at com.etranscript.eTranscriptBackendV2.web.api.ApplicantController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17e326c1.registerUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at com.etranscript.eTranscriptBackendV2.securityService.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:76) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at com.etranscript.eTranscriptBackendV2.securityService.security.CORSConfig.doFilter(CORSConfig.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:204) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Not necessarily because I can't remember where I declared a variable without assigning it

Comment: that is a different issue. the stacktrace should tell you exactly what line the error is one. possibly this: MimeMessage message = this.javaMailSender.createMimeMessage(); returned null.

Comment: "mimeMessage is null" This seems to be your MimeMessageHelper.
Is it possible that your Helper calls this getSentDate method? Does it have an internal MimeMessage?

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getSentDate()

Otherwise this getSentDate can also return null if the MimeMessage calling it doesn't have a Date field, or it's empty. But I'm not sure if your nullpointer is this or the previous guess.

Comment: @Stultuske I have added the complete stacktrace kindly take a look at it

Comment: Your MimeMessageHelper mimeMessage seems to be null when getSentDate is called.
Set a debug point on lines where mimeMessage is called or when it's initialized.